# buscar numero exacto en columnas de acuerdo a numero de la parte izquierda

Tags: excel, vba

Tengo esta macro

```
Sub busca_numeros()
Rem busca numeros iniciando en la celda a1
Dim unicos As New Collection
Set sorteo = Range("a2").CurrentRegion

With sorteo
    For i = 1 To .Columns.Count
        numero = Val(.Cells(1, i))
        On Error Resume Next
            unicos.Add numero, CStr(numero)
        On Error GoTo 0
    Next i

    Set numeros = Range("g:bw")
    
With numeros
    .Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
    For i = 1 To 4
        numero = unicos.Item(i)
        cuenta = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(numeros, numero)
        For j = 1 To cuenta
            If j = 1 Then Set xbusca = .Find(numero)
            If j > 1 Then Set xbusca = .FindNext(xbusca)
            Range(xbusca.Address).Interior.ColorIndex = 4
        Next j
    Next i
End With
End With
End Sub
```

y lo que hace es buscar todas las coincidencias de un numero de 4 cifras que esta ubicado en la parte izquierda pero lo que quiero es que busque el numero exacto en cada cuadro y no rellenar los demás coloco imagen de ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

les agradezco su ayuda

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: tenes que aclarar que es lo que falla y donde

Comment: gracias master por la aclaracion pero entonces que opcion tomo para escribir el codigo de igual como lo dejo usted

Comment: Puede agregar una mejor imagen? no se logra ver bien en detalle el archivo.

Comment: master este no es el problema que quiero solucionar ya he avanzado mas , el problema es a la pregunta "COMO PUEDO MEJORAR ESTE CODIGO EN EXCEL" ahi la imagen esta mas detallada si quiere envieme su correo y le envio el trabajo con los codigos ya hecho hasta donde voy